# Boxplot whisker don't match the calculated values

Tags: python, statistics, boxplot

Here is the figure of the box plot I made using:

```
plt.boxplot(data)
```

[image: boxplot]

I also calculated the values of Q1,Q3

```
Q1 , Q3 = np.percentile(data, [25,75])
Q1=101
Q3=123
```

Q1 and Q3 match the values of the box.

```
IQR = 22
Q3+1.5*IQR = 156
Q1-1.5*IQR = 68
```

Q3+1.5*IQR matches the whisker of the boxplot, but Q1-1.5*IQR does not match it.

Why?

for everyone curious here is the data:

```
data = [145, 137, 132, 131, 131, 130, 129, 128, 128, 127, 127, 127, 127, 131, 132, 131, 128, 126, 126, 127, 149, 138, 132, 130, 131, 129, 129, 127, 126, 125, 124, 123, 123, 124, 124, 124, 123, 122, 123, 129, 150, 138, 132, 129, 128, 127, 127, 126, 125, 122, 121, 119, 119, 118, 118, 118, 118, 118, 120, 131, 161, 141, 134, 131, 128, 127, 126, 125, 124, 121, 119, 117, 117, 115, 114, 113, 113, 114, 118, 136, 156, 143, 132, 128, 127, 126, 125, 125, 124, 120, 118, 116, 115, 112, 112, 110, 110, 111, 115, 135, 139, 134, 127, 125, 124, 123, 123, 122, 122, 118, 116, 115, 112, 111, 111, 108, 108, 109, 113, 130, 129, 125, 124, 123, 123, 123, 123, 121, 119, 117, 114, 112, 110, 108, 108, 106, 106, 106, 109, 119, 127, 122, 122, 122, 121, 121, 121, 120, 118, 116, 113, 110, 108, 106, 105, 104, 106, 104, 107, 112, 140, 125, 123, 122, 122, 121, 121, 119, 117, 114, 111, 109, 106, 104, 103, 102, 101, 102, 105, 108, 149, 129, 123, 122, 121, 120, 120, 117, 114, 111, 107, 105, 102, 101, 100, 99, 99, 100, 102, 105, 140, 129, 124, 122, 120, 120, 119, 115, 112, 108, 104, 101, 100, 99, 98, 98, 98, 99, 101, 105, 131, 126, 124, 122, 119, 118, 116, 114, 111, 107, 103, 98, 98, 98, 97, 97, 97, 99, 100, 104, 129, 126, 124, 121, 120, 118, 116, 113, 110, 106, 103, 96, 96, 97, 97, 96, 97, 101, 101, 104, 132, 127, 123, 120, 119, 118, 114, 111, 110, 105, 102, 99, 98, 96, 95, 95, 96, 97, 100, 104, 130, 125, 121, 119, 117, 114, 113, 109, 106, 104, 101, 98, 97, 95, 94, 95, 94, 95, 98, 101, 127, 123, 120, 117, 115, 112, 110, 107, 105, 102, 101, 98, 97, 94, 93, 93, 93, 94, 96, 99, 125, 122, 118, 115, 112, 110, 108, 105, 102, 100, 98, 97, 95, 93, 92, 91, 92, 92, 94, 97, 121, 119, 115, 113, 110, 108, 105, 103, 101, 99, 97, 96, 93, 92, 91, 91, 92, 92, 94, 97, 117, 117, 113, 113, 109, 106, 103, 101, 100, 97, 95, 94, 92, 91, 91, 90, 90, 92, 93, 97, 116, 117, 114, 111, 108, 105, 102, 100, 98, 97, 96, 93, 92, 90, 90, 90, 90, 91, 93, 97]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smallest number in data is 90 `min(data)` will give you 90. So, the whisker will end there. If you check the documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html), under the **whis** section "*... the lower whisker is at the lowest datum above Q1 - whis*(Q3-Q1),...*".

I believe that the whisker cuts off at the lowest point, if it happens to be above the 1.5*IQR, as it is in this case that is where it will end.

**EDIT**

Adding 68 to data gives...

[image]

Adding 60 (AND keeping 68) will show whisker till 68 and 60 shows up as an outlier

[image]

Comment: That is interesting. However when I add a new data point (<60) the lower whisker does not change.

Comment: If you add 68 (as per you calc it is the lower limit), whisker goes down till 68. If you add 60, that single number will show up as an outlier, as it is beyond (below) 68. Added the plots in response....

Comment: Thank you. That is incredibly confusing. Adding 67 does not change the whisker length, but adding 68 changes it, even though Q1-1.5*IQR stays the same.

Comment: Just add on 67 to the list, then keep adding a small number say 10 over and over. After a few additions, the median and the whisker will start to slowly move downwards. As you have a large list for data, this might take time, but you will see that the median, Q3, etc. will start moving down. Hope this helps.